# Find all the values of $w$ ∈ C that satisfy the equation.

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all values of $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\frac{\omega - \frac1\omega}{2i} = 2.$

So what I have is:

*Let $\omega$ be represented as $x + yi$ (by definition of complex numbers)*

*Then $\frac1\omega = \frac{x-yi}{x^2 + y^2}$ (by properties of complex numbers)*

*So, $\frac{x+yi - \frac{x-yi}{x^2 + y^2}}{2i} = 2$*

Eventually, I get, via expansion and simplification:

$\frac{x(x^2 + y^2 - 1) + yi(x^2 + y^2 + 1)}{2i(x^2 + y^2)}$

Any hints on how I can continue? I feel like I'm close but missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\frac{\omega - \frac1\omega}{2i} = 2\iff \omega - \frac1\omega=4i \stackrel{\omega \ne 0}{\iff} \omega^2-1=4i\omega\iff\omega^2-4i\omega-1=0.$$

This equation should be much more familiar.

Comment: So then, by equating imaginary and real parts, I get:

$\omega^2 - 1 = 0$ and $4i\omega = 0i$

where for the real part, I get $\omega = \pm 1$

Where do I go from there? Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Note that $\omega$ is complex! Apply the formula to solve a quadratic equation.

Comment: An equal sign was misleading, now corrected to $\iff$ (`\iff`).

Comment: @Did Thank you for noticing it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ordinary algebraic equation in the complex variable $\omega$, and in cases like this, it’s almost always not wise to look at the real and imaginary parts of $\omega$.

Just pretend you’re in high-school and solve:
\begin{align}
\omega + 1/\omega&=4i\\
\omega^2-4i\omega-1&=0\\
\omega=2i\pm\sqrt{-3}\\
\omega=(2\pm\sqrt3)i
\end{align}

Comment: So you answered using quadratic formula?

Comment: Yes I did. $a=1$, $b=-4i$, $c=-1$.